# Hadoop ClassNotFoundException with class that's imported anymore

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 with HBase 0.98.11 on Ubuntu 14.04

I was once using HBase. unfortunately it didn't work as expected. So, I decided to write the multioutput and filereader instead of using HBase. After commenting all HBase-related lines of code (also didn't include them in the javac -cp anymore), I still got the exception says "Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration".

I also tried format the namenode, delete datanode, and re-starting daemons, but it doesn't work.

I really have no idea why HBase still being included even if I comment and delete all (that I could think) of the HBase-related things.

Thank you in advance for every help.

Comment: you don't have hbase-x.xx.x.jar in classpath.

Comment: I had when I used hbase. But after I decided not to use hbase anymore I should remove it out?

Comment: You must have, somewhere in your configuration, a reference to HBase making the HBase jars to be (unsucessfully) loaded.

Comment: What I have checked are core-site, mapred-site, mapred-env, yarn-site, yarn-env, hadoop-env, hdfs-site. But all I found about hbase are some classpaths that were commented already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by changing the class' name of my hadoop jobs all the way from inside the code up to when compiling it.

I still have no idea why though.